# WordPress - fixing one post in one category. Url = domain.name/caterory/post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Good afternoon
I search through the a bunch of articles, but found nothing
I need a rigid binding one post in one category in CMS WordPress.
One post is linked to only one category.
The conclusion in the URL should appear automatically domain.name/category/post 
Post account must be displayed as a subcategory.

I understand that it is possible to score in the URL manually for each post, but the customer will not do this, it is necessary to prepare a convenient solution.

If such a functionality is not, is it possible to make the sub-edited as well as post that is, had a visual editor, content, heading through the admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure permalinkgs in Settings-> permalinks to be:

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```